# why is this code throwing a syntax error while rendering two different google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Can anyone help me figure out that why am i getting a syntax error when i call

```
        <div id='chart_div_org'></div>
```

in the html part.I could render the first chart earlier but this error came up when i    added another google chart to the script.I think i might have made some error
 while combining the two.Can someone please let me know the error.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         // Load the Visualization API and the orgchart package.
  google.load("visualization", "1.0", {packages:["corechart",'orgchart']});
   // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the org chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.

  function drawChart() {
    var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['PROGRAM', 'SUCCESSFUL STEPS',{ role: 'annotation' } ,'ERRORS',{ role:   
      'annotation' },'WARNINGS', { role: 'annotation' } ],
      ['Curian',  10, 'Completed ', 1,'Errors', 4, 'Warnings'],
      ['Pershing',  11, 'Completed ', 2, 'Errors',   4, 'Warnings'],
      ['DBTCA',  6, 'Completed'  , 3, 'Errors',  1, 'Warnings'],
      ['DBTCA',  1, 'Completed',  4, 'Errors',  5,  'Warnings']
    ]);

    var options1 = {
      title: 'CHECKLIST STEPS EXECUTION PROGRESS',
      hAxis: {title: 'PROGRAM', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };

    var chart1 = new 
    google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart1.draw(data1, options1);


    var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data2.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data2.addColumn('string', 'Location');

    data2.addRows([

      [{v:'FTP LOG', f:'FTP LOG'<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">FTP 
      LOG</div>'}, '', 'The type of log'],
      ['\\inf-ftp01-pri\Log\', 'FTP LOG', ''],
      ['\\inf-ftp02-pri\Log\', 'FTP LOG', ''],

    ]);
    var chart2 = new 
         google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_org'));
    chart2.draw(data2, {allowHtml:true});
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the syntax error you get? Please add more details which help to debug your problem.

Comment: do you have two divs with different ids ?

Comment: yes I do have two different divs with different div ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted invalid JSON:

```
data2.addRows([
    [{v:'FTP LOG', f:'FTP LOG'<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">FTP LOG</div>'}, '', 'The type of log'],
                             ^--closing quote---------------one more closing quote --^
```

More invalid JSON:

```
    ['\\inf-ftp02-pri\Log\', 'FTP LOG', ''], <----- remove this comma..
]
```

Backslashes need to be escaped, try the following:

```
['\\\\inf-ftp01-pri\\Log\\', 'FTP LOG', ''],
```

Also to correct the code

Given by @user3630022 -  you have 3 columns in the json but only 2 addColum

Comment: Thanks for this input..it surely was a point of error.I corrected it      to  [{v:'FTP LOG', f:'FTP LOG<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">FTP LOG</div>'}, '', 'The type of log'],  but it still is throwing a syntax error in the next line   ['\\inf-ftp01-pri\Log\', 'FTP LOG', ''],

Comment: yup...removed that as well...but still an error n the 2nd line

Comment: @user3630022 then it's a problem with the slashes, they are escape characters.

Comment: that did help as well.but now i am getting a different error. Uncaught Error: Row given with size different than 2 (the number of columns in the table).Uncaught Error: Row given with size different than 2 (the number of columns in the table). format+en,default+en,ui+en,orgchart+en,corechart+en.I.js:184
T.sY format+en,default+en,ui+en,orgchart+en,corechart+en.I.js:184
T.Cz format+en,default+en,ui+en,orgchart+en,corechart+en.I.js:185
drawChart

Comment: @user3630022 you have 3 columns in the json but only 2 `addColum`